# Python- Incomplete Data (Web Scraping)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
import sys


main_url = "http://sukhansara.com/سخن-سرا-پر-خوش-آمدید/newposts/parveenshakir/psghazals/"
test_url = urllib2.urlopen(main_url)
readHtml = test_url.read()
test_url.close()


soup = BeautifulSoup(readHtml, "html.parser")

url = soup.find('div',attrs={"class":"entry-content"}).findAll('div', attrs={"class":None})

count = 1

fobj = open('D:\Scrapping\parveen_again2.xml', 'w')
for getting in url:
   url = getting.find('a')
   if url.has_attr('href'):
          urls = url['href']       
          test_url = urllib2.urlopen(urls, timeout=36)
          readHtml = test_url.read()
          test_url.close()

          soup1 = BeautifulSoup(readHtml, "html.parser")

          title = soup1.find('title')
          title = title.get_text('+')
          title = title.split("|")

          author = soup1.find('div',attrs={"class":"entry-meta"}).find('span',attrs={"class":"categories-links"})


          author = author.findAll('a')

          fobj.write("<add><doc>\n")
          fobj.write("<field name=\"id\">sukhansara.com_pg1Author"+author[0].string.encode('utf8')+"Count"+str(count)+"</field>\n")
          fobj.write("<field name=\"title\">"+title[0].encode('utf8')+"</field>\n")
          fobj.write("<field name=\"content\">")

          count += 1


          poetry = soup1.find('div',attrs={"class":"entry-content"}).findAll('div')

          x=1
          check = True

          while check:
                 if poetry[x+1].string.encode('utf8') != author[0].string.encode('utf8'):
                        fobj.write(poetry[x].string.encode('utf8')+"|")
                        x+=1
                 else:
                        check = False
          fobj.write(poetry[x].string.encode('utf8'))

          fobj.write("</field>\n")
          fobj.write("<field name=\"group\">ur_poetry</field>\n")
          fobj.write("<field name=\"author\">"+author[0].string.encode('utf8')+"</field>\n")
          fobj.write("<field name=\"url\">"+urls+"</field>\n")
          fobj.write("<add><doc>\n\n")



fobj.close()

print "Done printing"
```

Sonetimes I get 24 poetry from 24 urls and sometimes 81. But there are almost 100 urls? Every time when i reach 81 this error occur

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

or sometime set timeout error. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Switching to [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and maintaining an *opened session* should make it work:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    main_url = "http://sukhansara.com/سخن-سرا-پر-خوش-آمدید/newposts/parveenshakir/psghazals/"

    readHtml = session.get(main_url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(readHtml, "html.parser")

    # ...
```